# Find list with the largest number of elements in a list of list

Tags: kdb

How to find the list which has the largest number of elements in a list of list?

For instance, say I have the following list of list:

```
l : (`AAPL`GOOG;`AAPL;`MSFT`JPM`GOOG`BNP;`JPM)
```

and I want to return `` `MSFT`JPM`GOOG`BNP ``

which is the list with the highest number of elements (4 elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:

```
first l where c=max c:count each  l
```

Counts each list, gets the position of largest count and indexes into original list with this

Comment: You need to add `first` at the start to get the actual list. Without it, it is a list of list.

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer will fail depending on the symbol compositions.

```
q)l : (`AAPL`GOOG;`AAPL;`MSFT`JPM`GOOG`BNP;`ZZZZ`ZZZZ`ZZZZ)
q)l first idesc l
`ZZZZ`ZZZZ`ZZZZ
```

The following will work, regardless of the list contents

```
q)l first idesc count each l
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is

`1#desc l`

or you can replace `1#` with `first` to make it more readable

Comment: So this isn't the best answer, consider the following. 
q)l : (`AAPL`GOOG;`AAPL;`MSFT`JPM`GOOG`BNP;`ZZZZ`XXXX`YYYY)
q)l idesc l
``` `ZZZZ`XXXX`YYYY```

It's enumerating the symbols, so the `ZZZZ` is greater than `MSFT`

Comment: Essentially, this will fail depending on the symbols used in each list, `Z` > `A` for symbols in kdb

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of it here's another option

```
l first idesc l
```

Find the highest descending grade and use this as an index.

Comment: This will not give the correct answer for all lists.  Try this example from Callum Biggs answer: (\`AAPL\`GOOG;\`AAPL;\`MSFT\`JPM\`GOOG\`BNP;\`ZZZZ\`ZZZZ\`ZZZZ)